# is there a way to join them?

Tags: php

file A has some data as this:

```
$_ADMINLANG['global']['hometitle'] = 
$_ADMINLANG['global']['searchfilter'] = 
.....
```

file B has some data as this:

```
"test a";
"test B";
```

is there  a way to join them in file C as this:

```
$_ADMINLANG['global']['hometitle'] = "test a";
$_ADMINLANG['global']['searchfilter'] =  "test B";
.....
```

thank you.

Comment: some IDE with column copy paste should help you, can you rephrase your question as it is very vague

Comment: which IDE can do that? i want to put B file content after A file content line by line

Comment: forget about launching an IDE, I gave a solution using Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this using excel/open office calc, copy and paste the content of file a in one coulmn, paste the content of file b in second column in third column set up a formula like this `=$A1&$B1` and drag it till the length of the data you have, you will have `$_ADMINLANG['global']['hometitle'] = "test a";` in 3rd column, why bother a programming language when it can be done by some other way, if you dont have excel/openoffice, try using spreadsheets on Google docs

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you can do

```
paste -d ' ' a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```